# Does facebook login require that I use PFUser in my application (using parse.com)?

Tags: ios, parse-platform

I am using Parse.com as the backend to my app, and I want to enable login through Facebook. Problem is, I want to make my own User class for my app so that I don't have to conform to certain PFUser traits (such as required password/username, using Parse for e-mail verification, etc).

Is there a way to use Parse's facebook log-in without having to use PFUser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main use case for using Parse's Facebook integration is it's built-in linking to PFUser objects. For your use case, you can use the Facebook SDK directly instead.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to make a custom user class just to handle facebook login. Parse can authentic purely through Facebook (i.e. no user name, email, password)

From their [documentation:...](https://parse.com/docs/ios_guide#fbusers-signup/iOS)

> There are two main ways to use Facebook with your Parse users: (1) to
>   log in (or sign up) as a Facebook user and creating a PFUser, or (2)
>   linking Facebook to an existing PFUser.
>
> Log In & Sign Up
>
> PFUser provides a way to allow your users to log in or sign up through
>   Facebook. This is done by using the logInWithFacebook method like so:

```
[PFFacebookUtils logInWithPermissions:permissions block:^(PFUser
*user, NSError *error) {
    if (!user) {
        NSLog(@"Uh oh. The user cancelled the Facebook login.");
    } else if (user.isNew) {
        NSLog(@"User signed up and logged in through Facebook!");
    } else {
        NSLog(@"User logged in through Facebook!");
    } }];
```

> Parse is compatible with version 3.2 of the Facebook iOS SDK.
>
> When this code is run, the following happens:
>
> The user is shown the Facebook login dialog. 
>   The user authenticates via Facebook, and your app receives a callback using handleOpenUrl.
>   Our SDK receives the Facebook data and saves it to a PFUser. If it's a new user based on the Facebook ID, then that user is created. 
>   Your code block is called with the user.

Comment: How to create a PFUser with Facebook data myself without using PFFacebookUtils ? Because, I also use Google+ login for which you didn't provide any API. So I need it to for both in one way. and also please explain how to authenticate on every launch using my custom facebook integration.

Comment: PFUser is for private data for that user - Parse needs some way to authenticate. If you don't need private data, you can 'login' other APIs (google etc) and then have an anonymous users (look at PFAnonymousUtils)